# ReportViewer Visual Studio 2022 Wrong Calculation because 0 value

Tags: rdlc, visual-studio-2022, reportviewer

I have a problem in my project

The calculation is wrong because there is 0 value on one of my other calculation
Here the report looks like

[Here What My ReportViewer Result Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLtmj.png)

And here the expression that i use

[Here What Expression I Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egvFb.png)

if i remove the expression
"ReportItems!GTCategoryC.Value"
the calculation became right but if i change the date and category c not null then it will be wrong

i need the calculation to be right even if category c or any other category is not null

What Should i do to fix it?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason that make the calculation wrong is **NULL** Value
So I try to make an exception in the expression
Here what the Right Expression Are

```
=IIf(Fields!TicketId.Value Is Nothing, 0, Count(Fields!TicketId.Value))
```

This change the **NULL** value to 0 (Zero)